# Comparing strings using == in an if

Tags: php

I'm having trouble when trying to compare strings in an "if" statement.

```
if ($alarmonoff == "on") {
    echo("checked");
}
else {
    echo("unchecked");
}
```

In my code, even when  $alarmonoff contains "on" (checked by displaying it before the statement), the displayed text is still "unchecked". Is there anything wrong? Isn't my syntax correct?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As I can't post code in answer comments, I'm posting this here as user689 asked. The $alarmonoff variable comes from a JSON string:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("./settings.json","r");
    $settings = fread($handle, 512);
    $jsonsettings = json_decode($settings, true);
    extract($jsonsettings);
    fclose($handle);
    $alarmonoff = strtolower(trim($alarmonoff));
    echo $alarmonoff;
    function alarmonoffcheck () {
        if ($alarmonoff == "on") {
            echo("checked");
        }
        else {
            echo("unchecked");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: check the spaces and the invisible characters such as chr(13), chr(10) ...

Comment: Doubtful.  There's nothing wrong with the code you show.  Do a `var_dump($alarmonoff)`

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think that $alarmonoff isn't being set properly.

Comment: Try to `echo($alarmonoff)` and provide the result!

Comment: echo $alarmonoff gives "on", without quotes of course. I don't think there are any invisible characters (if you meant spaces Sebas), because when I try to highlight the echoed value, I can only select the two letters "o" and "n"...

Comment: In this case you'll have to show us the complete code, there is nothing wrong.with this code.

Comment: See my edit for the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using this

```
$alarmonoff = strtolower(trim($alarmonoff));
```

This way you know that you have no blank space and a random capital won't invalidate your check.

After looking at the context of the code, $alarmonoff is out of scope, you're referencing a global variable in a local scope.

Add

```
global $alarmonoff;
```

at the top of the function alarmonoffcheck() to reference the global variable that was defined earlier.

Comment: Could you post some more code for context, maybe some snippet of where it was set? Also make sure it was in the same scope as this block.

Comment: Sure, check my original question for the code, I've edited it!

Comment: The variable is out of scope, you either need to call it by reference or change the header of the function to include a variable so you can pass it to the function.

Comment: Or add this line in your function before you check the string:

    global $alarmonoff;

that will use the global version of this variable